# No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe error

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I am experiencing the strange problem with No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe

when i run JUNIT Test case of any DAO it is inserting fine. But when i run in server it is giving No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE

i have added ojdbc14.jar to WEB-INF/lib folder.

here is the jdbc.properties

Comment: What application server are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error because you did not make the oracle jdbc thin driver library available when running your program.

Download the Oracle jdbc library. 
add it to the classpath when running your program.

What is the server you are trying to run  on it?